# sql Append for value with single quotes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

am having below query

```
DECLARE @fNAME varchar(40) = 'Obrain'
DECLARE @query nvarchar(256)
SET @query = 'UPDATE TableName SET columnname = ''' + @fNAME + ''''
select @query
```

which results as expected

```
UPDATE TableName SET columnname = 'Obrain'
```

But if i change input @fname with single quotes

```
    DECLARE @fNAME varchar(40) = 'O''brain'
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(256)
    SET @query = 'UPDATE TableName SET columnname = ''' + @fNAME + ''''
    select @query
```

i get below result where am having issue with single quotes

```
UPDATE TableName SET columnname = 'O'brain'
```

1. How do i fix this query with minor changes
2. What is the better way to do this

Comment: Either escape it or set quoted identifiers.

Comment: Double the internal quotes in the `@fname` declaration: `'O''''brain'` One set gets interpreted immediately, while the second pair remains after you build the query. Also try `replace(@s, char(39), char(39)+char(39))`. Of course Gordon is right that the proper way to deal with parameters is not string concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this?  Use `sp_executesql` and parameters:

```
DECLARE @fNAME varchar(40) = 'O''brain';
DECLARE @query nvarchar(256);
SET @query = '
    UPDATE TableName SET columnname = @fNAME'

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@fNAME varchar(40)', @fName=@fName;
```

Comment: Thank you lets say if i want to append something on the query some text and another parameter. how do i handle this

Comment: am expecting my fNAME Updated by +AnotherParmaeter on+ date

Comment: @Peru Please always post YOUR REAL PROBLEM, not a dumbed-down version that isn't actually your problem.

Comment: @Peru . . . I believe this answers your question (or at least the question you should have asked which is about executing the SQL string).  If you have another question, ask it as another question, not a comment.

Comment: Agreed !! I know it is a !! dumbed-down version..Will correct it

Comment: @GordonLinoff  still trying to figure out and added a seprate question..