# sql Append for value with single quotes - String Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server

This extended version on my previous question [sql Append for value with single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937856/sql-append-for-value-with-single-quotes/48937921?noredirect=1#comment84890122_48937921)  which am trying to fix

```
DECLARE @fNAME varchar(40) = 'O'brain'
DECLARE @query nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @id nvarchar(5) = '8'
SET @query = 'UPDATE TableName SET columnname = ''' + @fNAME + '''' +'Added on '+ GETDATE() + ''' WHERE Id= ' + convert(nvarchar, @id)
```

am trying to get below output using 
EXEC sp_executesql

```
Update table name set columnname = 'O''brain Added on Aug  8 2017 11:15AM' where id = 8
```

Basically am trying to append some text and current date along with name to be updates as text in one column

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql in the first place? I don't see anything in this question or your other one that requires dynamic sql. It seems to be adding a layer of complexity that isn't needed.

Comment: @SeanLange can you suggest how better this can be done..? as per Gordon i thought this is the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define and execute the query as:

```
DECLARE @fNAME varchar(40) = 'O''brain';
DECLARE @query nvarchar(256);    
DECLARE @id nvarchar(5) = '8';

SET @query = '
UPDATE TableName
    SET columnname = @fNAME + '' added on '' + convert(varchar(255), GETDATE() )
    WHERE Id = @id';

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@fname varchar(40), @id nvarchar(5)', @fname=@fname, @id=@id;
```

Note:  This is not going to format the date exactly as in your question.  You haven't chosen a formatting for the date in your code, so I didn't either.

Comment: syntax error on added "Incorrect syntax near 'added'."

Comment: Adding another single quote to string '' added on ''  fixed it  .. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do this with a normal update. There appears to be no reason at all to use dynamic sql here.

```
DECLARE @fNAME varchar(40) = 'O''brain';
DECLARE @id nvarchar(5) = '8';

Update TableName
set columnname = @fNAME + ' added on ' + convert(varchar(255), getdate())
```

Comment: but this will fail if name has single quotes right ?

Comment: No it won't fail. It isn't using dynamic sql so the extra layer of confusion is no longer present. This would result in the columnname value being O'brain added on 2018-02-23

Comment: Thank you !! Ok i think i got more confused and over think !! I like this keep it simple !! Thank you again !!